# how to get text in second QListWidget, the second QListWidget is in QStackedWidget connect to first QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I want to get text in second QListWidget, but it will give me wrong row number.

I know how to get text in a QListWidget, just use

```
QListWidget.currentRow()
```

to get row number and

```
QListWidget.currentItem().text()
```

to get text

But the text in second QListWidget, the second QListWidget is in QStackedWidget connect to first QListWidget, the row will always print(-1) and can't print(currentItem().text()

So How can I do to get text in second QListWidget?

Example code is here:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from numpy.random import randint 

# data 
d = {i: [j for j in randint(100, size=10)] for i in randint(100, size=10)}
d_key = list(d.keys())

class MainTest(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        mhbox = QHBoxLayout()

        # create first QlistWidget = self.leftlist
        self.leftlist = QListWidget()
        self.Stack = QStackedWidget()
        self.stack = {}
        for i in range(len(d_key)):
            self.leftlist.insertItem(i, f"{d_key[i]}") # create item with key in d
            self.stack[i] = QWidget()
            self.Stack.addWidget(self.stack[i])
            self.stack_ui(i)
        mhbox.addWidget(self.leftlist)
        mhbox.addWidget(self.Stack)
        self.leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.Stack.setCurrentIndex)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(mhbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.show()
    
    def stack_ui(self, i):
        list_in_key = d[d_key[i]] # get list in d[key]
        
        self.leftlist_in_leftlist = QListWidget()
        for n in range(len(list_in_key)):
            self.leftlist_in_leftlist.insertItem(n, f"{list_in_key[n]}")
        
        self.leftlist_in_leftlist.currentRowChanged.connect(self.get_name)
        
        self.hbox_in_leftlist = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox_in_leftlist.addWidget(self.leftlist_in_leftlist)
        self.stack[i].setLayout(self.hbox_in_leftlist)
    
    def get_name(self):
        print(self.leftlist_in_leftlist.currentRow()) # always give me -1
        # print(self.leftlist_in_leftlist.currentItem().text()) # can't not print, it's will get wrong.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MainTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You're creating *and overwriting* `self.leftlist_in_leftlist` every time you call `stack_ui`, meaning that the one in `get_name` will always be the *last* created one. Either use `self.sender()` or access the *current* QListWidget based on the QStackedWidget current page.

Comment: self.sender() is very useful in my case, thank you.